# Sending message from register service worker to client page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, service-worker

I am trying to send a variable(boolean) to the app.js when the registration onupdatefound function is triggered , so whenever a new update is received the app.js will know and then i can show a popup with a refresh button.

most of the part i have implemented , i am just confused as how my app.js will receive data on "message" addEventListener as i am not able to receive any data from it.

thanking you in advance.

> registerServiceWorker.js

```
    registration.onupdatefound = () => {
     console.log('sw onupdatefound');
     const installingWorker = registration.installing;
      installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
      console.log('sw onstatechange',navigator.serviceWorker);
      if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
        console.log('sw onstatechange//',navigator.serviceWorker);

        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {

          // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
          console.log('New content is available; please refresh...');

          navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({
            data: {
              toUpdate: true,
            },
          });

        } else {
          console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
        }
      }
    };
  };
```

> service-worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
 console.log('in fetch of s-w');
self.clients.matchAll().then(all => all.map(client => client.postMessage(event)));
});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
 console.log('event msg from s-w', event.data);
if (event.data.toUpdate) {
 console.log('updating');
self.skipWaiting();
}
// Select who we want to respond to
self.clients.matchAll().then(all => all.map(client => client.postMessage(event.data)));
self.clients
 .matchAll({
   includeUncontrolled: true,
   type: 'window',
 })
.then((clients) => {
  clients.postMessage(event.data);
  if (clients && clients.length) {
    // Send a response - the clients
    // array is ordered by last focused
    clients[0].postMessage(event.data);
  }
 });
});
```

> app.js

```
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
 console.log('event in app.js nav on msg', event);
 if (event.data.toUpdate) {
  alert('Please refresh your page to upadate service worker');
 }
};

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => { console.log('new event ====>', event); });
```

Answer (score 4):

In CRA v3 `onSuccess` and `onUpdate` callbacks can be passed as `options` to `serviceWorker.register`.

Typically those callbacks update the application store which in turn would affect the UI components.

For a minimal CRA v3 demo:

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {message: 'Hello World'};

    // setup callback to get
    // service worker installation status
    //
    this.props.listen(status => {
      this.setState({message: status});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p className="App">{this.state.message}</p>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const {listen, onUpdate, onSuccess} = setupStatusTransfer();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App listen={ listen } />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.register({
  onUpdate,
  onSuccess
});

function setupStatusTransfer() {
  let cb;
  let status;

  const send = s => {
    status = s;
    if(cb && status) cb(status);
  }

  const listen = callback => {
    cb = callback;
    send(status);
  };

  return {
    listen,
    onUpdate: makeSendStatus(send, 'update'),
    onSuccess: makeSendStatus(send, 'success')
  };
}

function makeSendStatus(send, status) {
  return _registration => {
    send(status);
  };
}
```

See also: [Let Users Know When You Have Updated Your Service Workers in Create React App](https://medium.com/better-programming/let-users-know-when-you-have-updated-your-service-worker-in-create-react-app-b0c2701995b3).

---

Are you attempting to notify all currently open tabs (windows) that are being served by the service worker? That could be somewhat problematic as you are relying on the **old service worker** to correctly process the message being posted to it by the **new registration** - ultimately you have no idea how *out of date* the currently active service worker is.

That being said, to process the `postMessages` within a React component you should use the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods (or `useEffect` hook).

The following simplified example uses a dedicated Web Worker with `workerize-loader` but the principle remains the same:

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: '?'};

    const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(navigator.language, {minimumIntegerDigits: 6});
    this.receive = event => {
      const { data: count } = event;
      if (typeof count === 'number') {
        this.setState({count: nf.format(count)});
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.worker.addEventListener('message', this.receive);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.worker.removeEventListener('message', this.receive);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <p className="App">{this.state.count}</p>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
// App.js with hooks
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App({ worker }) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState('?');
  const subscribe = () => {
    return listenForUpdates(worker, setCount);
  }
  useEffect(subscribe, [worker]);

  return (
      <p className="App">{ count }</p>
  );
}

function listenForUpdates(worker, setCount) {
  const nf = new Intl.NumberFormat(
    navigator.language,
    {minimumIntegerDigits: 6}
  );

  const receive = ({ data })  => {
    if (typeof data === 'number') {
      setCount(nf.format(data));
    }
  };

  const cleanup = () => {
    worker.removeEventListener('message', receive)
  };

  worker.addEventListener('message', receive);

  return cleanup;
}

export default App;
```

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import worker from 'workerize-loader!./worker';

let instance = worker();

instance.start(1000);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App worker={ instance } />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
// worker.js for https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader
//
export function start(delay) {
  let count = 0;
  const sendAndUpdate = () => {
    postMessage(count);
    ++count;
  };

  setInterval(sendAndUpdate, delay);
}
```

`addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` should be available on the `ServiceWorker` interface obtainable from `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`.

(Your `app.js` example tries `navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage` - but `navigator.serviceWorker` is the [`ServiceWorkerContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer) - the [`ServiceWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) is found on `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` - that's where the [`onmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/onmessage) property can be found).

---

Update: With Create React App 4 [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) has become opt-in, i.e. is no longer included in the default CRA template.

ServiceWorker is included in `cra-template-pwa` ([Making a Progessive Web App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/)) which itself uses ServiceWorker via [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) libraries.

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

The ServiceWorker registration logic has been segregated into `serviceWorkerRegistration.js` - separately from the `service-worker.js`. Furthermore the ServiceWorker is only registered for production builds being served. To build:

```sh
yarn run build
```

And then serve, like:

```sh
http-server -c-1 ./build
```

Minimal `cra-template-pwa` v4 demo:

```js
// file: registrationStatus.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

let current = 'Unchanged';
const subscriptions = new Set();

function subscribe(setStatus) {
  subscriptions.add(setStatus);

  return () => {
    subscriptions.delete(setStatus);
  };
}

function dispatch(status) {
  current = status;
  subscriptions.forEach((setStatus) => setStatus(status));
}

function useStatus() {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(current);
  useEffect(() => subscribe(setStatus), []);

  return status;
}

// Updated but waiting for stale tabs to close
function onUpdate(_registration) {
  dispatch('Updated');
}

// Updated and running
function onSuccess(_registration) {
  dispatch('Successful');
}

export { useStatus, onUpdate, onSuccess };
```

```js
// file: App.js

import { useStatus } from './registrationStatus';

function App() {
  const status = useStatus();

  return <p className="App">Registration status: {status}</p>;
}

export default App;
```

```js
// file: index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from './serviceWorkerRegistration';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { onUpdate, onSuccess } from './registrationStatus';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorkerRegistration.register({
  onUpdate,
  onSuccess,
});

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: @Akshay Added minimal v4 cra-template-pwa demo.